# Proving that if $\alpha \neq 0$ then $\alpha \cdot \beta$ is limit when $\beta$ is limit ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

This is my problem. 
I have to prove that if $\alpha \neq 0$ is any ordinal then $\alpha \cdot \beta$ is a limit ordinal when  $\beta$ is limit ordinal. 
The definition of limit ordinal I have is that $A$ is a limit ordinal if for each $\alpha \in A$, it is true that: $\alpha+1 \in A$
So I tried to use the definition but can't see a clear answer.

¿There are another equivalences of limit ordinals I can use? 
¿Any hint?

Please and thank you !

Comment: Exactly how are you defining the product?

Comment: $\alpha \cdot \beta = \sup\{\alpha \cdot \gamma : \gamma < \beta\}$ whenever $\beta$ is limit ordinal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove the following fact first:

> $A$ is a limit ordinal if and only if $\sup\{\alpha\in A\mid\alpha+1\in A\}=A$.

In other words, you don't have to check that *for every* $\alpha\in A$, $\alpha+1$ is also in $A$. Just unboundedly many of them.

Next, $\alpha\cdot\beta=\sup\{\alpha\cdot\gamma\mid\gamma<\beta\}$, and since $\alpha>0$, you can check that $(\alpha\cdot\gamma)+1\leq(\alpha\cdot\gamma)+\alpha=\alpha\cdot(\gamma+1)$.  Finally, apply the fact.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the recursive definition of product and $\delta<\alpha·\beta$, pick $\gamma<\beta$ with $\delta<\alpha·\gamma$. Then
$$
\delta+1 < \alpha·\gamma +1 \le \alpha·\gamma + \alpha =\alpha ·(\gamma +1) \le \alpha\cdot\beta
$$
because $\gamma+1<\beta$.

If you're using the definition $\alpha\cdot\beta =\text{otp}(\beta\times \alpha)$ (ordered lexicographically), then any pair $(\xi,\zeta)$ is lexicographically below $(\xi+1,\zeta)$, so that $\beta\times \alpha$ has no largest element, and so neither does $\alpha\cdot\beta$ (under $\in$). But then $\alpha\cdot \beta$ is a limit.